# How to group by using months with ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My transaction data in mongoDb looks like this

```
[
{ _id=ObjectId("597f77280000000000000000")},
{ _id=ObjectId("597f77280000000000000001")},
{ _id=ObjectId("597f77280000000000000004")},
]
```

I want to get the count of the total number of transactions in each month. I am using the aggregate function and till now it looks like this.

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{month:{$month:_id.getTimestamp()}}}
{$group: {_id: $month, count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong here since I am not very experienced in mongoDb. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: give valid data then only make query easily

Comment: give some sample data

Comment: Hi @Vinoth this is a sample data itself. From the ObjectId's I can get the month and I want to group the transactions by month as to how many transactions in each month.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{ month: { $month: "$your_date_field" }}},
{$group: {_id: "$month", count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

It gives expected result(**On the basis of records on my machine**)

> ...{
>       "_id" : 11,
>       "count" : 30.0 }
>   {
>       "_id" : 12,
>       "count" : 16.0 }...